# CORS error React native web with Nginx + Django

Tags: django, nginx

I've faced CORS error with EC2 Django + Nginx server. Have no idea why it never works.

*Error:*

```
Access to fetch at 'https://serveraddress/api/v1/user' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

*How I requestsed*

```
  fetch(`https://${env.apiUrl}/api/v1/user`, {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":'true',
      Authorization: await getToken(),
    },
```

Also tried with using Authorization header or request get, post request auth is not requried, but none of them worked.
Plus, tried with axios, xmlhttprequest and none of them worked..

Followings are settings for Nginx + Django

*Nginx Settings*

```
location / {
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
    proxy_pass http://web/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

*Django Settings*

All the settings for cors including django-cors-headers middleware and put corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware on the top of it.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     ....
    ]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r"^https://\w+\.domain\.com$",
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['*']
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['*']
```

Also checked preflight message using curl options and got < HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

```
curl --verbose --request OPTIONS 'https://serveraddress/api/v1/user/profile' --header 'Origin: https://localhost:19006' --header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Origin, Accept, Content-Type' --header 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET'
```

It works find on Android or iOS but it never works on web.

I've found there is similar issues with React but, it can be solved with http-proxy-middleware or add proxy on `package.json`.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/
But it seems I can't set proxy for react native web.

Comment: can you try to add this to nginx `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';`

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko thank your for the comment! I've just tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked! It was Nginx problem.
Adding the followings to location / did the trick

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD,DELETE';
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    return 204;
}
```